# How can I open a new screen by using a string?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have a function for opening a new activity, but I wan't to use a string for that. My function is shown below. I think my question is clear if you see that.

```
public boolean showScreen(String screen) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, screen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

EDIT:// The error is gone if I use try and catch. My system works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Class.forName(String s) to get the Class for the specific string.

Code:

```
public boolean showScreen(String screen) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(screen));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I change my function to that I get an Error by Class.forName(screen):
Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException

Comment: You have to set the correct class name including the package name.

Comment: What is string's value? Is it the fully qualified name, e.g. `com.vries.app.TheClass`?

Comment: Yes, it is. But the error stands before the function, and not before the place where I use the function.

Comment: Yes, I did. The function works fine if I use `classname.class` as second parameter, but that doesn't work if I use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an enum and change the parameter to it. Or at least parse the String to the respective enum. Then you can switch over it.